# How do you introduce a new widget between two others when you click on a button with pack (tkinter) on Python 3x?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, position, frame, pack

If I click on the the button "+" next to Monday, I would like to get the combobox under Monday; 
If I click on the the button "+" next to Tuesday, I would like to get the combobox under Tuesday; etc.

Though, currently, the comboboxes go under Saturday only as the picture shows it below.

[image]

How do you think I could change my code to get that result?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

Working_Days = {0: "Monday", 1: "Tuesday", 2: "Wednesday", 3: "Thursday", 4: "Friday", 5: "Saturday"}
D = [d for d in Working_Days]


def products():
    demand_per_day = Frame(Days_screen)
    demand_per_day.pack(fill=X, side=TOP)
    product = Combobox(demand_per_day, values=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), width=10)
    product.current(0)  # set the selected item
    product.pack(side=LEFT, padx=35)


def Days():
   global Days_screen
   global day
   Days_screen = Tk()
   Days_screen.geometry("450x600")

   for d in D:
      day = Frame(Days_screen)
      day.pack(fill=X, side=TOP, pady=10)
      Label(day, text=Working_Days[d], font=("Calibri", 12)).pack(side=LEFT, pady=10, padx=10)
      Button(day, text="+", width=2, command=products).pack(side=LEFT, pady=10)

   Days_screen.mainloop()

Days()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pack` documentation includes information about many options, including the options `before` and `after`, which you can use to insert widgets before or after other widgets.